# Undefined info command: "goroutines"

Tags: go, gdb

I'm new to golang. I was debugging my go application.

While I tried to run "info goroutines", it threw out:

```
Undefined info command: "goroutines".  
Try "help info
```

What did I miss in my gdb configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article "[Debugging Go Code with GDB](https://golang.org/doc/gdb)" does mention:

```
(gdb) info goroutines
```

But only in the context of loading extension scripts for a given binary.

> The tool chain uses this to extend GDB with a handful of commands to inspect internals of the runtime code (such as goroutines) and to pretty print the built-in map, slice and channel types.
>
> If you'd like to see how this works, or want to extend it, take a look at [src/pkg/runtime/runtime-gdb.py](https://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/runtime-gdb.py) in the Go source distribution.
>   It depends on some special magic types (`hash<T,U>`) and variables (`runtime.m` and `runtime.g`) that the linker (`src/cmd/ld/dwarf.c`) ensures are described in the DWARF code.
>
> If you're interested in what the debugging information looks like, run '`objdump -W 6.out`' and browse through the .debug_* sections.

So make sure your debug session is run with those extensions activated.

Answer (score 0):

in the gdb session run

```
source $GOROOT/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
```

where $GOROOT is go lives (see `go env | grep ROOT`)

you should use https://github.com/go-delve/delve as recommended by golang docs https://golang.org/doc/gdb